# Pointer writing to memory loop in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to understand pointers and curious about some things. For example If I run this or this kind of program can I change the values of some hexadecimals that is not used by this program? Does OS do something to defend itself?

```
    int num1 = 1;
    int num2 = 2;
    int *var1,var2;

    var2 = num1 + num2;
    var1 = &var2;

    for (int counter1 = 0; counter1 < 100000; counter1++) {
        
        *(var1 + counter1) = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Platform dependent, but most OSes do. Other times were left behind , somewhat 40 years ago. How runtime will react to it isa different question. Indefined Behaviour.

Comment: The program simply has undefined behaviour. Though most of the time, code like this will seg fault because reads/mutates restricted memory.

Comment: Thank you for answers but how the memory editor programs access these memory then?

Comment: Even within a program doing that can easily cause crashes. If you overwrite something on the call stack, it will typically crash when the function returns  or shortly after. In you write up in the call stack, then you could overwrite local variables and if those are classes with virtual functions or destructors, probability of a crash is high. Even for basic types, it can lead to all sort of problem as messing null terminated strings or indexes into an array.

Comment: Also because your code contains undefined behavior, final program might not do what you think because optimizer sometime assumes that a program does not contains any undefined behavior to do some optimisation like reordering instructions. **Because of that, it is somewhat pointless to try to understand program containing undefined behavior**. Also, compiler might notice that written memory is never used and remove that code.

Comment: There are cases where there is nothing defined at a given address.  Not all of memory is defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On most modern OS's, your process's memory is isolated from that of every other process and the OS itself.  So while your code can trash your own process's memory and do a lot of damage, you can't harm other processes in this way, nor can you harm the OS.

Brief historical note: this was not always the case, and it's still not the case in some OSes (typically for embedded devices, specialized electronics, etc).  In those situations, you absolutely can trash the memory of the whole system and of other processes.  That's one reason that versions of Windows before Windows XP (ME, 95, 3.1, etc) were so unstable.  One rogue process could torpedo the whole system.

Code that is privileged can usually read or write the memory of other processes, even today.

Comment: Can you open up "Code that is privileged" please, do you mean admin rights?

Comment: Not just admin rights, processes (on Windows anyway) have security tokens and you may need to elevate to access a process's memory.  Which you can do if you have admin rights, but it needs to be explicitly requested.  See the WriteProcessMemory docs another commenter linked to you.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it depends where you run it, but usually there is [memory protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection), which means you can't just write outside of the processes memory.

Comment: Makes sense, but there are memory editing programs, means they can access other program's memories. How are they doing that then?

Comment: @RisenShadow Sometimes there are functions provided by the OS, for example in Windows there is [ReadProcessMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and [WriteProcessMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-writeprocessmemory). I am not sure about linux but I think ptrace can be used for things like these there.

Comment: @RisenShadow Mainly the OS will change what memory is accessible each time their is a thread (process) context switch. Thus each program generally only has access to its own memory (sandbox).

Comment: @Phil1970 but still doesn't explain how memory editing programs access them

Comment: @likle the links to ReadProcessMemory and WriteProcessMemory are a great addition to your answer, thanks!